# Как сделать метод отвечающий за акцию "купи 2 получи 3"?

Tags: java, классы, list, методы

Здравсвуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой с созданием функции, которая будет отвечать за акцию "купить СТОЛЬКО получи СТОЛЬКО" (Например купи 2 получи 3).

Есть класс `Store`, в котором добавляются товары. Класс `Basket`, собственно говоря корзина, куда "кладутся" товары. Класс `BuyMorePayLess`, класс где нужно реализовать акцию.

Менеджер сам решает, на какой товар будет проведена акция (Сникерс - купи 2, поулчи 3, Орео - купи 5 получи 10 и т.д.)

То есть, в классе `Store` есть List с товарами `static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();` и нужно как реализовать эту идею. Сижу ломаю голову, не понимаю как это сделать.

Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Promo {
  int buy;
  int get;
  Promo(int buy, int get) {
    this.buy = buy;
    this.get = get;
  }
}

Map<Item, Promo> promos = new HashMap<>();

int recalculateQuantity(Item item, int qty) {
  Promo promo = promos.get(item);
  if (promo == null)
    return qty;

  return qty / promo.buy * promo.get + qty % promo.buy;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]