# Почему не выводится List?

Tags: java, list

Не понимаю, почему не выводится List в методе `getIds()`, который находится в классе `BuyMorePayLess` и вызывается в классе `Menu`. Сам метод `getIds()`:

```
    public void getIds() {
            for (int i = 0; i < idsForPromotion.size(); i++) {
                if (idsForPromotion.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("There is no items");
                }
                idsForPromotion.get(i);
            }
    }
```

Метод `define()` в классе `BuyMorePayLess` должен добавлять int значение в List:

```
    public void define() {

        System.out.println("What item you would like to choose for promotion?");
        int chooseItem = input.nextInt();

        idsForPromotion.add(chooseItem);

    }
```

В классе `Menu` в методе `startMenu()`, есть case где и должен вызываться метод `getIds()`:

```
case 7:
      buyMorePayLess.getIds();
      break;
```

в классе `Menu` есть `BuyMorePayLess buyMorePayLess = new BuyMorePayLess();`. Не могу понять почему не выводится List. Не выводиться ни *"There is no items"*, ни элемент листа.

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void getIds() {
  if (idsForPromotion.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("There is no items");
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < idsForPromotion.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(idsForPromotion.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```